Creating sprinting and stamina mechanic in 3d Godot game
I’m creating a 3d doom like game and I want to create a sprinting mechanic that will lower the stamina bar, then once that bar reaches 0 it should stop you from sprinting.
My current code:
Player.gd
(this is in process delta btw)
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Shift") and $"../../Control".stamina >= 1:
        SPEED = sprintspeed
    else:
        SPEED = 5

Stamina.gd
func _process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Shift"):
            value -= 0.505

func _on_timer_timeout():
    if value <= 99:
        value += 1

Almost everything works, the sprint bar decreases when shift is pressed, and regens when released, it sets the speed to the sprint speed (15) and sets it back to 5 when released. But when it reaches 0 it doesn't stop you from sprinting.

Can you show whatever code is responsible for keeping value and stamina in sync, as well as any getters/setters involved.

In Stamina.gd you are setting some 'value' variable.
But in the Player.gd you are reading from Stamina a 'stamina' variable.
